# Laravel 7 giving 500 error when accessing external api when the response returned with status of 104 (but working for for status 200)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My question is I am accessing some external rest api like getServices if the get services response is like this

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "country": "india",
            "qualfication": "B.tech",
            "educationId": 13,
            "city": "Mathurafgddsfwf",
            "endDate": null,
            "clgUniversity": "amar Nath",
            "startDate": "2010-05-22"
        }
    ]
}
```

everything is working fine for the above response  from the external Api

but when the response is like this from external Api it is giving 500 error in browser

```
{
    "status": 104,
    "message": " not exist",
    "data": []
}
```

my controller code is

```
  public function getEducation(Request $request){
    //   dd($request);
        
        $cookie = \Cookie::get('datastore');
        $dataJson=json_decode($cookie,true);
        $username=$dataJson['data']['username'];
        $token= $dataJson['data']['token'];
        $phoneSecurity= $dataJson['data']['phone'];
        $userId=$dataJson['data']['userId'];
  
    
       

        $client =new Client();
        $data=array(  "username"=>$username,
        );
      
  
        $dataJson=json_encode($data);

        $headers['Content-Type']="application/json";
        $headers['X-Access-Token']=$token;
    
        $response=$client->request('POST',
        'http://localhost:8084/api/users/getUserEducationDetails'
        ,array("headers"=>$headers,"body"=>$dataJson));

        $body=$response->getBody()->getContents();
        $resText=json_decode($body,true);


      if(  $resText['status']==200)
        return response()->json($resText);
        if($resText['status']==104)
        {
            $newData=array("status"=>"104");
            $newData=json_encode($newData);
            $resText=$newData;
        }
      
        return response()->json($resText);
    }
```

In short when the external api returning  response like this
{
"status": 104,
"message": " not exist",
"data": []
}
laravel gives 500 internal server error

And the error showed inside the network tab inside response is

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST http://localhost:8084/api/enimm/users/getUserEducationDetails` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:
{"status":104,"message":" not exist","data":[]}
 in file C:\xampp\htdocs\OodeatSocialFinal\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php on line 113
```

Comment: are you sure this url http://localhost:8084/api/enimm/users/getUserEducationDetails is working fine?

Comment: yes this is my backend and it is returning the 200 with data when there is data in it for this it works fine but when there is no data than in that case response format is above written In short the api is fine I even tested with postman

Comment: you can use   return response()->json($resText,104);     instead of     return response()->json($resText);

Comment: yeah tried that but the error is still there its like laravel is giving error when the status is 104

Comment: so we are sure that the problem is here return response()->json($resText);?

Comment: I think the error is that laravel reads 104 status and converts into default exception something

Comment: Yea, I tested it and 104 gives an error, why do you want 104 especially as http status code here

Comment: I think it's better to use the standard codes to refer that the data is not found like 404